# obtener los ultimos registros mayores y repetidos sin agrupar mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo una tabla

```
id_periodo '| id_mesa
1               1
1               1
2               1
2               1
```

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar el último `id_periodo` mayor ?

estube probando

SELECT id_periodo, id_mesa
FROM tabla  where id_mesa=1 ORDER BY id_periodo DESC limit 1
pero solo muestra un registro

el resultado tiene que dar así

```
id_periodo| id_mesa

2               1
2               1
```

Comment: Hola Fmcv. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: A que te referís con los últimos? Cuantos tendrían que ser?

Comment: no hay limite de cuantos tendría que ser solo mostrar los registros con el id_periodo mayor

Comment: Ahí edité la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entendí, lo que tenes que hacer es ordenar los registros según tu criterio, en este caso `id_periodo` de manera descendiente, luego, haces uso de `LIMIT` para que devuelva la cantidad de registros que necesitas.

Por ejemplo;

**Tabla y Registros:**

```
CREATE TABLE ejemplo (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_periodo int,
    id_productos int,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO ejemplo (id_periodo, id_productos) 
   values
    ("1","1"),
    ("1","2"),
    ("2","2"),
    ("2","1")
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM ejemplo
ORDER BY id_periodo DESC
LIMIT 2
```

**Resultado:**

```
| id | id_periodo | id_productos |
|----|------------|--------------|
|  4 |          2 |            1 |
|  3 |          2 |            2 |
```

Dejo el [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a0d72/2/0) para que lo veas en práctica

**EDIT**

Después de leer tu comentario, para hacer lo que necesitas, podes hacer una **Subquery**, quedaría de la siguiente manera;

```
SELECT *
FROM ejemplo
WHERE id_periodo = (SELECT max(id_periodo) from ejemplo)
```

**Resultado**

```
| id | id_periodo | id_productos |
|----|------------|--------------|
|  3 |          2 |            2 |
|  4 |          2 |            1 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a0d72/3/0)**

Comment: Gracias pero Limite de registros no es fijo es dinámico

Comment: @FmcvMcv lo que necesitas es una subquery, ahí modifiqué la respuesta

Comment: Muchas Gracias Juan Salvador Portugal